# I need 120 volts DC (yes, direct current) at 20 amperes

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc, power-electronics

**I want direct current at mains voltage--120 volts DC up to 20 amperes.**  I don't want the DC output voltage to exceed 120VDC.  I'll be rectifying from 120VAC single-phase mains.  I want efficient non-linear DC output voltage regulation to 120 volts; I'll appreciate tips where efficiently regulating the output of a 120 VDC 20A mains-supplied rectifier (with a minimum of components) is concerned.

Comment: So what is your specific question?

Comment: Assuming the 120VAC mains are already well regulated, use a variac (autotransformer) to step down to about 85VAC (or 70.7%) before the full-wave bridge recitifer -- this should result in 120VDC. **Caution:** an autotransformer does not provide galvanic isolation, so rectifier output is referenced to mains neutral, making any exposed circuitry potentially lethal.

Comment: If you use an isolation transformer before the Variac you will be safe and able to make measurements with your normal grounded scope .The isolation transformer will be good wieghtlifting practice.

Comment: http://www.bellnw.com/manufacturer/Lambda/GEN-150-22.htm

Comment: If you directly rectify 120VAC from mains you'll have ~170VDC. At 20 amps you're dealing with extremely deadly power. I don't know why you think you need to do this but this is extremely dangerous and I don't think you are experienced enough to be able to do this safely.

Comment: derstrom8:  I am aware of the effect of the peak voltage's effect here & I am well aware of the dangers of electricity; why I think I need it isn't your concern & I don't need to be patronized.

Comment: MarkU & Autistic: Thank you, that's an interesting idea, as it's unlikely I'll ever find a 120V - 85V transformer.

Comment: Andy aka:  English is my first language.

Answer (score 5):

**Rectifiying mains directly without some form of galvanic isolation extremely dangerous and stupid.  If you don't heed this advice, you are not competent to work with mains electricity and you will kill someone, or kill yourself.

*Consider yourself warned.***

Mains voltage is about 170V peak, and if you rectified it, this is about the voltage you would see. 120VAC is referring to the RMS voltage, which for a sine wave is Vpeak/√2.  It is a sine wave that slews from 170V to -170V, 120VDC is closer to 85VAC.

So how are you going to step down your rectified and filtered ~170VDC to 120VDC efficiently with a minimum amount of components? At 2400W?

You aren't.  What you've asked is mutually exclusive and in multiple ways.  You can do it simply but with terrible efficiency using linear regulation.  This will bleed off the voltage difference between the input and output as heat.  170V-120V is 50V.  So at 20A, you'll be dumping 1000W of heat, while delivering 2400W to the load, which is pretty piss poor.  It IS 70% efficiency, but at this much output power, even 95% is still 120W of waste heat to deal with.

Your only other option is a buck converter, which is very much the opposite of minimum component count or simple.  And since you're insisting on doing this to the rectified output of mains (which you shouldn't be for safety reasons anyway), that means the buck converter must switch 170VDC on and off, regardless of what the output will be.  And at 20A.  No such buck converter exists.  And there is no reason to build one.

Instead of doing the dangerous thing you've described.... your only option that will be efficient and have that kind of regulation at that output power is a full bridge switch mode power supply.  Good luck building one with 2400W output.  It certainly won't be with minimum numbers of components.  It will be a fairly massive undertaking.

I suggest you buy a suitable supply.  Unfortunately, a quick look on Mouser turned up nothing that fit your requirements.  You'll have to put two 60V 20A supplies in series, and they'll have to be bench supplies to have that capability.  Any commercial supply will have suitable isolation, but any bare SMPS will have be grounded to earth, preventing them from being put in series.

Here is one such suitable supply, it's only $2100.  You'll need two of course, but it looks like Mouser only has 1 in stock right now.  Good luck.

http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/BK-Precision/XLN6024/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMs2%252bVrH5rwl1of5BrOEXweAeBRFe4JxA%252b4%3d

Comment: Just a note, AC mains is not 170V pk-pk, it's 170V pk

Comment: @JohnSFO, please take this onboard. If you had enough experience or training to do this safely, you wouldn't have asked the question in the first place. We can't impart a lifetimes worth of tinkering and a college degree in power electronics in an answer post.

Comment: Sean Boddy: Take THIS onboard.  What a bloody impudent, patronizing remark!  As useless a response as it is snide!

Comment: Dave Tweed/metacolin: Again, I'm aware of the dangers of electricity; a simple admonition to relieve you of any guilt in case I burn or electrocute myself will suffice--rather like the one from MarkU above.  I'm already aware of the facts of par. 2.  Par. 4; acknowledged.  The remainder is... interesting.  I am aware of the attributes of galvanic isolation.  Thank you.

Comment: So, if anyone has anything helpful or useful to convey, please do.  I thought this site was an information-sharing site, not a forum to berate or denigrate people who pose questions that may be regarded (by some) as unusual.  If it can be done, say so; if it's difficult or easy, say so.  Hazardous?  Admonitions without condescending remarks are certainly not unwelcome, but keep it civil, like MarkU.  The remarks in Mr. Boddy's & derstrom8's responses are simply deplorable.  Over all, this was a negative experience--pun intended.

Comment: PS for any & all concerned:  My occupation has placed me in close proximity to 600VDC tractive power; 600 volts is certainly enough pressure to burn or electrocute.  I am quite capable of working safely with DC power under 200 volts.

Comment: @JohnSFO, I genuinely hope you will come back and try to engage with the community again at some point in the future. I stand by what I said though. The simple fact is that if you don't already personally know how to design and implement a high voltage rectifier, then you also don't know how to do it safely. Switched mode power supplies can be designed fairly simply. If you're diligent in your studies I expect you could have a working design with about  two hours of study and one hour to work out the math. And please use the @ symbol to ping users you reply to.